# Pandas fillna() data types

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I created dataframe to test fillna() method for NaN values.

```
col1 = [np.nan,1,2,3]
col2 = [2,3,4,np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2})


   col1 col2
0   NaN 2.0
1   1.0 3.0
2   2.0 4.0
3   3.0 NaN


df.info()

RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   col1    3 non-null      float64
 1   col2    3 non-null      float64
```

After fillna() that replace NaN with "". data type becomes "object".

```
df.fillna("").info()

RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col1    4 non-null      object
 1   col2    4 non-null      object
```

Is there a way to keep the data types as "float64" after fillna()?

```
df.fillna("").astype({'col1': 'float64', 'col2': 'float64'})
```

I also try to convert the data back to "float64" but failed with error message
"ValueError: could not convert string to float".

Appreciate your advice.

Comment: how can the empty string `""` be a float?

Comment: @QuangHoang I understand an empty string can't be a float. Actually I have a few dataset for economy data which have similar condition. The columns are region, country, gdp per capita, healthcare spend etc. So I use fillna() method to replace NaN. All the columns turn into 'object' type which doesn't allow me to perform calculation. What could be the solution?

Comment: Use fillna(value=0.0) for the Numerical columns (where you want to perform calculations). For categorical columns use fillna("")

Comment: @SaravanakumarV I want to apply this to economic data such income per person (gdp per capita). There is difference between "No data" & Zero. Imagine I draw a line chart for multiple years. The chart will show very different meaning.That's why i want to replace NaN with empty string if the cell doesn't have data.